# Why is the EVM designed to have "private variables"?

Tags: evm, storage, nonce, state-trie, ethereum-design

In EVM, one contract is able to read `code` and `balance` of any addresses. However, `storage` and `nonce` of other addresses is not accessible.

Since all states are public on the blockchain, why is EVM designed to have "private variables"? i.e. What's the drawback of making the world state (`nonce`, `balance`, `storage`, `code` of all addresses) fully visible to EVM?

Comment: Check out this post it explains it well https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79603/what-are-private-variables-in-solidity

Comment: I concur.
This is a useless restriction making us spend more gas. Lets say you need to access total supply of DAI token inside your contract, knowing the storage location where the DAI contract stores the 'total_supply' variable you would just use single `SLOAD` instruction instead of an extra `CALL` and lots of other opcodes that will drain your budget. You can propose this at https://eips.ethereum.org/